# Present simple vs past simple

Tags: difference

If somebody call me,after hey hello,what should I say ,
1.what was the reason of your call?
OR
2. What is the reason of your call?

Comment: why don't you ask a why question? "why are you calling me?"

Comment: Usually, after your greeting, the person called starts explaining why they are calling. You could say "I am listening (to you)" to make the caller talk.

Comment: What's the situation? Expectations of telephone manner depend on where you are - home, workplace, etc. If workplace, the sort of workplace. Also, what do you think it should be? Why are you unsure?

Answer (score 1):

As you want to ask the question during the call, which is happening in that current time, then you should use the present simple tense like this:

> What **is** the reason **for/of** your call?

If it happened that you finished the call and met that person in a later time, then use the past simple tense as the call had been completed in some time in the past regardless of how much time had passed. It could be only a few minutes or seconds. As long as the event/action has finished, the past tense is used.

> What **was** the reason **for/of** your call?

- Both **of** and **for** work, but "for" sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

I think "reason *for* your call" sounds better than "reason *of* your call", but either verb tense works fine.

The act of placing the phone call was a single event which was completed in full, so from that point of view, the "call" is in the past, and you can ask, "what *was* the reason for your call?"

But you can also take the view that the "call" is a lasting activity that is going on throughout the conversation. If this is your interpretation, the "call" is in the present, and you can ask, "What *is* the reason for your call?"

So both "is" and "was" are equally correct. It just depends on your meaning for "call": making/placing the phone call? -- or conversing during the phone call?